# Link to different page after validation blazor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

Hi I want to ask is there a way to submit validate and link to other page in **BLAZOR**
Thats how I link cancellation to other page

```
 <NavLink href="@($"/personal/list/1")">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CloseModal">@Loc["cancel"]</button>
 </NavLink>
```

Thats my submmit button

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">@Loc["save"]</button>
```

Thats the Edit model for the button thats inside it

```
<EditForm Model="PersModel" OnValidSubmit="@CreatePersonal">
<FluentValidator TValidator="PersonalViewModelValidator" />
```

Thats the connection on Valid submmit to the API

```
  protected async Task CreatePersonal()
{
    var token = Storage["JWT-Token"];
    bool personalExist = false;
    Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    //Convert Selected values into the Pers database values
    PersModel.Pers.Group = PersModel.SelectedGruppe?.Name;
    PersModel.Pers.Anrede = PersModel.SelectedAnredeName;
    PersModel.Pers.Grad = PersModel.SelectedGradName;
    PersModel.Pers.Titel = PersModel.SelectedTitelName;
    PersModel.Pers.Department = PersModel.SelectedAbteilungName;
    PersModel.Pers.Group = PersModel.SelectedGruppeName;
    PersModel.Pers.PrevDepartment = PersModel.SelectedPrevAbteilungName;
    PersModel.Pers.PrevGroup = PersModel.SelectedPrevGruppeName;
    PersModel.Pers.Uni = PersModel.SelectedStaetteName;
    //on input select after editing the --Select-- is converted into value


    try
    {
        BoolValue uh = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<BoolValue>(Storage["environment_uri"] + "/personal/exists/" + PersModel.Pers.PersName);
        personalExist = uh.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogWarning(ex, "Failed to load  BoolValue uh");
        Storage.SetItem("Transaction", "errorload");
    }


    if (personalExist == false && PersModel.Pers.PersName != "_add_")
    {
        await Http.PostAsJsonAsync(Storage.GetItem("environment_uri") + "/personal", PersModel.Pers); // thats the one i add here

        Storage.SetItem("Transaction", "modified");
        await OnParametersSetAsync();
        CloseModal();

    }
    else if (isEdit == true)
    {
        // here was post in original
        await Http.PutAsJsonAsync(Storage.GetItem("environment_uri") + "/personal", PersModel.Pers); // this update
        CloseModal();
        Storage.SetItem("Transaction", "modified");
        await OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
    else if (isEdit == false && personalExist == true)
    {

        Storage.SetItem("Transaction", "errorsame");
        await OnParametersSetAsync();

    }


}
```

Thats the Validation class

```
 public PersonalViewModelValidator()
    {
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.PersName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.Bezeichnung).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.Id).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.Street).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.HouseNumber).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.PLZ).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.Location).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.DateHired).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.FullTime).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("A valid email address is required.");

        //rule for the sieze max
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.Comment_1).Length(0,40).WithMessage("Must be less than 40 characters");
        RuleFor(data => data.Pers.Comment_2).Length(0,40).WithMessage("Must be less than 40 characters");

        // not working
        RuleFor(data => data.SelectedAbteilungName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("is a required field.");
        RuleFor(data => data.SelectedGruppeName).NotNull().WithMessage("is a required field.");

        //RuleFor(data => data.SelectedAbteilung).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Abteilung  is a required field.");
        //RuleFor(data => data.SelectedGruppe).NotNull().WithMessage("Test test");
    }
```

So what is to SUBMIT all this information get feedback if there is validation errors etc link to the another page and get the message from Toaster for example

```
NavLink href="@($"/personal/list/1")


@if (Storage.GetItem("Transaction") == "modified")
```

{

```
Toaster.Success(@TLoc["success1"], @TLoc["success2"]);
Storage.RemoveItem("Transaction");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it

```
   [Inject]
public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

  protected void NavigateToOverview()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/personal/list/1");
}
```

and then you just call this method after the result from the API

```
 NavigateToOverview();
```

in my case was

```
  else if (isEdit == true)
{
    // here was post in original
    await Http.PutAsJsonAsync(Storage.GetItem("environment_uri") + "/personal", PersModel.Pers); // this update
    CloseModal();
    Storage.SetItem("Transaction", "modified");
    await OnParametersSetAsync();
   NavigateToOverview();
}
```